# How to calculate an mathematic expresion reciving values from sliders

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am new in Shiny and i am trying to learn. My issue is that i want to calculate an mathematic expresion by giving a value from slider and in the end to show the result. Until now i have made the following code but it is wrong. Could you please guide me.

Thanks in advance

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

# Define UI for slider demo app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  #Navbar structure for UI
  navbarPage("SAR Model", theme = shinytheme("united"),
             tabPanel("Toblers Function", fluid = TRUE),
             # App title ----
             titlePanel("Toblers Fuction"),
             
             # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
             sidebarLayout(
               
               # Sidebar to demonstrate various slider options ----
               sidebarPanel(
                 
                 # Input: Slope interval with step value ----
                 sliderInput("slope", "Slope:",
                             min = -0.60, max = 0.50,
                             value = 0.0, step = 0.01),
                 
               ),
               
               # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
               mainPanel( 
                 
                 # Output: Table summarizing the values entered ----
                 tableOutput("values")
                 
               )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Reactive expression to create data frame off input value ----
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    
    data.frame(
      Name = c("Slope"),
      
      Value = as.character(c(input$slope)),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })
  
  Value$toblers <- 6*exp(-3.5*input$slope)
  
  
  # Show the values in an HTML table ----
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })
  
  output$tobler <-renderText({value$toblers})
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `input$slope` outside of a reactive context which is not allowed. Define a reactive for your calculation of toblers and then display this, like:

```
toblers <- reactive({
            6*exp(-3.5*input$slope)
})

output$tobler <-renderText({toblers()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i made some changes but does not show the result.
Here is the code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

# Define UI for slider demo app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  #Navbar structure for UI
  navbarPage("SAR Model", theme = shinytheme("united"),
             tabPanel("Toblers Function", fluid = TRUE),
             # App title ----
             titlePanel("Toblers Fuction"),
             
             # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
             sidebarLayout(
               
               # Sidebar to demonstrate various slider options ----
               sidebarPanel(
                 
                 # Input: Slope interval with step value ----
                 sliderInput("slope", "Slope:",
                             min = -0.60, max = 0.50,
                             value = 0.0, step = 0.01)),
          
               
               # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
               mainPanel( 
                 
                 # Output: Table summarizing the values entered ----
                 tableOutput("values"),
                 
            
               )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Reactive expression to create data frame off input value ----
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    
    data.frame(
      Name = c("Slope"),
      
      Value = as.character(c(input$slope)),
      stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  })
 
  
 
  # Show the values in an HTML table ----
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })
  output$slope <- renderText({
    paste0("The speed is ", 6*exp(-3.5*input$slope),"Km/h")
  })
  
 }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but know does not appear the table with the value from slider.
Any opinion why?
here is the code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

# Define UI for slider demo app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  #Navbar structure for UI
  navbarPage("SAR Model", theme = shinytheme("united"),
             tabPanel("Toblers Function", fluid = TRUE),
             # App title ----
             titlePanel("Toblers Fuction"),
             
             # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
             sidebarLayout(
               
               # Sidebar to demonstrate various slider options ----
               sidebarPanel(
                 
                 # Input: Slope interval with step value ----
                 sliderInput("slope", "Slope:",
                             min = -0.60, max = 0.50,
                             value = 0.0, step = 0.01)),
               
               
               # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
               mainPanel( 
                 
                 # Output: Table summarizing the values entered ----
                 tableOutput("Values"),
                 tableOutput("slope")
                 
                 
               )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Reactive expression to create data frame off input value ----
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    
    data.frame(
      Name = c("Slope"),
      
      Value = as.character(c(input$slope)),
      stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  })
  
  
  
  # Show the values in an HTML table ----
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })
  output$slope <- renderText({
    paste0("The speed is ", 6*exp(-3.5*abs(input$slope+0.05)),"Km/h")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```